# Check if xml file exists in memory WP7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, isolatedstoragefile

I make the download of an xml file from the internet to the memory phone.. I want to see if the internet connection is available to make the download and send a message if not. And if not i want to see if the xml file as already present in the memory.. if present, the appliccation doesn't make the download.

The problem is i don't know how to make the "if" condition to see if the file exists.

I have this code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            Uri xmlUri = new Uri("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32613258/file_xml.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
            downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Downloaded);
            downloader.DownloadStringAsync(xmlUri);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The internet connection is not available");
        }
    }

    void Downloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the xml-file");
        }
        else
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("xml_file.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage);
            using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                string xml_file = e.Result.ToString();
                writeFile.WriteLine(xml_file);
                writeFile.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to see if the file exist with a condition :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IsolatedStorageFile class has a method called `FileExists`. See the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.fileexists.aspx)
If you want to check for just the fileName you can also, use the `GetFileNames` method which gives you the list of file names of files in the root of the IsolatedStorage. [Documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190395.aspx)

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if(myIsolatedStorage.FileExists("yourxmlfile.xml))
{
    // do this
}
else
{
    // do that
}
```

or

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
string[] fileNames = myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames("*.xml")
foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
    if(fileName == "yourxmlfile.xml")
    {
      // do this
    }
    else
    {
      // do that
    }
}
```

I will not guarantee that the above code will work exactly, but this is the general idea of how to go about it.

Comment: but what i do in the condition? I don't understand:(   if(getfilename.xml_file=true)????????

Comment: Also, I am not sure if foreach will work with string arrays. Try the usual for loop.